# Why is yield statement of a javascript generator function returning parameters of .next()?

Tags: javascript, yield

I stumbled on [generator functions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and what puzzles me is the following example:

```
function* logGenerator() {
  console.log(yield);
  console.log(yield);
  console.log(yield);
}

var gen = logGenerator();

// the first call of next executes from the start of the function
// until the first yield statement
gen.next(); 
gen.next('pretzel'); // pretzel
gen.next('california'); // california
gen.next('mayonnaise'); // mayonnaise
```

What I don't understand is why the `yield` statement which is the argument of `console.log` returns the parameter passed to the `.next()` method of the generator. Is this happening because an empty `yield` must return the value of the first parameter of the `.next()` method?

I have also tried some more examples, which seem to confirm the above statement like:

```
gen.next(1,2,3); // the printed value is 1, the 2 and 3 are ignored
// and the actual yielded value is undefined
```

Also is there a way to access the further parameters of the `.next()` method inside the body of the generator function?

Another thing I noticed is, while the yield statement is returning these values to the `console.log` they are actually not yielded as the output of the generator. I must say I find it very confusing.

Comment: ...because that's what's supposed to happen? Why does this confuse you?

Comment: That's just what a `yield` expression evaluates to.

Comment: @user2357112 it confuses me because I do not see the parameter to be referenced in the above code. Having read the links from the answers it all makes sense now but when I first saw it I didn't understand it. As a side note, you can also do things like `function* x() {yield yield yield;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question. I think reading the MDN on the `.next()` method is most helpful. You can define the value you want to pass within the generator function itself (i.e. `yield 1`) or pass the value via `next()` by saying something like `gen.next(1)`

The `next()` method itself returns an Object, with the properties `value` and a boolean `done` which signifies whether the generator function is complete (i.e. exhausted of available outputs and will now output only `undefined` for a value).

That said, there are two ways to access / pass it that `value`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next

Answer (score 2):

The confusion comes from the fact that `yield` and `next` have different syntaxes, while they actually do the same thing. Generator and its caller are symmetric (that's why they are called "co"-routines and not "sub"-routines). Both functions can be thought as connected by a communication channel, and can either do their job or sleep waiting for an incoming message in the channel. The only difference is that the generator is initially asleep (that is, there's an implicit "listen" command at the top of it), while the caller is initially awake.

Both `yield` and `next` do the same <s>thing</s> three things:

- write its argument to the channel
- fall asleep and listen for an incoming message
- emit the incoming message as its value and wake up (that is, carry on with what's below them)

Illustration:

```js
_ = console.log.bind(console)

function *gen() {
    _('gen: good morning')

    _('gen: sending hi')
    _('gen: zzz')
    p = yield 'hi'
    _('gen: awake! got', p)

    _('gen: now sending fine')
    _('gen: zzz')
    p = yield 'fine'
    _('gen: awake! got', p) // ***
}

function main() {

    var g = gen()

    _('main: sending knock knock')
    _('main: zzz')
    r = g.next('knock knock')
    _('main: awake! got', r)

    _('main: sending how r u')
    _('main: zzz')
    r = g.next('how r u')
    _('main: awake! got', r)
}

main()
```

Note that since write comes before read, the very first message sent to the generator is lost. It's only used to wake up the generator. Also note how we've left the generator in the sleeping state, so the `***` line is not reached.

Answer (score 0):

[This makes it quite clear:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield)

> [rv] = yield [expression];

**expression** Defines the value to return from the generator function via the iterator protocol. If omitted, undefined is returned instead.

**rv** Returns the optional value passed to the generator's next() method to resume its execution.

Basically you're printing out the parameter you've sent through to continue execution.